# Redirect Match creating a loop htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I would like to make all instances of this URL
     **http://www.site.com/questions/page**
to go to this url
     **http://www.site.com/members-home/questions/page**

When I try to add a rule in .htacess to handle this, it creates a loop because it finds the same folder name in both versions of the url.

```
 Redirectmatch 301 /questions/page/(.*)$ http://www.site.com/members-home/questions/page/$1
```

Is there a way in .htaccess to do this?  Or is there another better way?  This is for wordpress by the way and I'm trying to fix a breadcrumb problem.

Comment: Why are you using RedirectMatch for this in the first place, instead of just Redirect? With the latter, you would not even have had this problem.

Comment: So redirect will redirect all the pages?  such as /page/1, /page/2 etc?  I thought that was what redirectmatch was for?

Comment: And I thought you might have read the manual before asking … [Then any request _beginning_ with URL-path will return a redirect request to the client at the location of the target URL. Additional path information beyond the matched URL-path _will be appended to the target URL_.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression matches the end of a url. With both urls the end are the same, so a redirect loop. By enhancing you regular expression you can fix your problem

For example, this might work:

```
Redirectmatch 301 ^/questions/page/(.*)$ http://www.site.com/members-home/questions/page/$1
```